# HTML5 canvas collision-detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

Can anyone please help me out with a small test game I'm creating. I'm basically creating this game to learn a few things about HTML5 and so far it's all been good. I've been able to create a canvas with a air balloon that can fly and drops to the bottom when it's not. Now I want the air balloon to be able to stop on another block image, which I've called "level1". If someone could perhaps have a [look at it](http://tehwebz.com/html5/game.php) and view the source and suggest how I would do this, I would appreciate it. Thanks again. :)

EDIT: Or perhaps this isn't the most efficient way to create a level. If it isn't then please say. :)

http://tehwebz.com/html5/game.php

Answer (score 0):

As you did with "landing on the bottom"

```
if (playerPosY >= canvas.height - playerImg.height) {
    playerVelY = 0;
    playerPosY = canvas.height - playerImg.height;
}
else {
    playerVelY += 0.8;
}
```

you need the balloon to stop falling when it reaches the coordinates of the level. I guess there is nothing wrong with your level, you just have to set the playerVelY to 0.